# VMware - persistent "Host memory status" alarm in vSphere

Tags: memory, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, vmware-esx

I have a particular VMWare ESX 4.1 host that has a very persistent "Host memory status" alarm.

This is running on an HP ProLiant DL360 G7 server. The HP ILO and System Management agents don't know any errors. If I clear the alarm in the vSphere client, it returns within a day. I've tried reseating DIMMs, however, the error does not indicate a problem with a specific module.

There's another host in the cluster with an identical configuration. It's not exhibiting any issues.

Any thoughts?

This is touched on briefly on [other forums](http://www.arstechnica.tv/civis/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=1144835) (and [here](http://www.cb-net.co.uk/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=124:hp-bl465c-g7-esxi-41-issues&catid=17:performance&Itemid=12)) with no clear resolution.

[image]

Comment: Anything in the IML logs? both on the same firmware? sounds like a HW issue to me

Comment: IML is clean. SMH is clean. No LEDs/indicators on the front display.

Comment: In a position to shut them both down and swap their disks? see if the problem stayed with the HW or code? Otherwise I'd say it's a HW problem and get HP to fix it.

Comment: I could swap DIMMs or order warranty replacements. But since the error doesn't specify a slot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

whens the last time you've updated the HP ESXi stuff?  There could be a bug in thier HW pack that's been resolved, or provides more info.

Comment: Updated to the newest ESX 4.1 update Wednesday. I'll try updating the PSP now.

Comment: It's been a day, and I've had no errors since. So updating the HP ProLiant Support Pack seems to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and this article solved it.  I ended up having to perform all 9 steps.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2011531

> To resolve this issue, you must clear warnings and errors from the
> *Hardware Status* tab in VMware vCenter Server.
>
> To clear warnings and errors from the *Hardware Status* tab:
>
> 1. Go to the *Hardware Status* tab.
> 2. Click the **System event log** view.
> 3. Click **Reset event log**.
> 4. Click **Update**. The error clears.
> 5. Click the **Alerts and warnings** view.
> 6. Click **Reset sensors**.
> 7. Click **Update**. The memory clears.
>
> **Note**: If the error does not clear, connect, connect to the host via
> SSH. For more information, see [Enabling root SSH login on an ESX host
> (8375637)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=8375637).
>
> 8. Run this command to restart the sfcbd service:
>    `services.sh restart`
>
>    Run this command to restart the service in ESX:
>    `/etc/init.d/sfcbd-watchdog restart`
> 9. Click **Update**. The error clears.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Reset event log did the trick for me! I was scratching my head over this discrepancy for a day now, but finally it it solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem recently on my HP Proliant DL360 G9 and VCenter 5.5. Here is the magic sequence from [Cannot clear Hardware Status warnings and errors in VMware vCenter Server 4.x and 5.x](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2011531) that helped:

To clear warnings and errors from the **Hardware Status** tab:

> 1. Click the **Hardware Status** tab.
> 2. Click the **System event log** view.
> 3. Click **Reset event log**.
> 4. Click **Update** to clear the error.
> 5. Click the **Alerts and warnings** view.
> 6. Click **Reset sensors**.
> 7. Click **Update** to clear the memory.
>
> Note: If the error does not clear, connect to the host via
>   SSH
>
> 8. Run this command to restart the `sfcbd` service:
>
>    `services.sh restart`
>
>    Run this command to restart the `service` in ESX:
>
>    `/etc/init.d/sfcbd-watchdog restart`
> 9. Click **Update**.

See also [Warnings in the Hardware Status tab of the ESXi 5.x host fails to clear](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2061093) documents for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the "Host Memory Status" alarm in vCenter 7.0.2 for a Dell R640. I logged into the Dell's iDRAC and there was a RAM error:

```
The memory health monitor feature has detected a degradation
in the DIMM installed in DIMM_A1.

Reboot system to initiate self-heal process.
```

So sometimes the error is a **real hardware error**.

After rebooting iDRAC showed:

```
The self-heal operation successfully completed at DIMM DIMM_A1.
```

... and vCenter stopped complaining.

After that I went and Googled "self-healing dimm" and learned what the technology is behind that message. I hadn't realized that there were DIMM problems that could be "self healed", but there are!